# Where does the $\frac{1}{2}$ go/disappear when computing the law of this RV?

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

Suppose that we have a random variable $X$ such that $X$ ~ $\textit{N}(0,3)$. We are asked to compute the law of $X^2$ and my answer is different from the solution by  $\frac{1}{2}$. Help me please figure out where does it go.
Let $Y$ be a random variable s.t $Y = X^2$. Then $\phi(X^2)=\phi(Y)$.
$\mathbb{P}_{X}$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt {6\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{6}}$ and $y = x^2$, $dy = 2xdx$ $\Leftrightarrow dx = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}dy$
I'll quote the **Transfer Theorem**. I study in French, so I haven't quite found the equivalent definition in English textbooks.

> Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak{B}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X: (\Omega, \mathfrak{B}, \mathbb{P}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a RV s.t. the law of $X$ is $\mathbb{P}_{X}$.
> For any measurable function $\phi:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{+}}$  we have $\int_{\mathbb{\Omega}}\phi(X(\omega))d\mathbb{P(\omega)} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)d\mathbb{P}_{X}$

Using this, we get $E[\phi(Y)]=\int_{\Omega}\phi(y)d\mathbb{P}_{Y}(y)=E[\phi(X^2)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x^2)d\mathbb{P}_{X}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x^2)\frac{1}{\sqrt {6\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{6}}dx$.
Using $y=x^2$ we get $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(y)\frac{1}{\sqrt {6\pi}}e^{-\frac{y}{6}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\mathbb{I}_{\mathbb{R^{*}_{+}}}(y)dy = \int_{]0; \infty[}\phi(y)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{6 \pi y}}e^{-\frac{y}{6}}dy$
Therefore the law of $Y$ is $d\mathbb{P}_{Y} = \mathbb{I}_{]0;\infty[}(y)\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{6 \pi y}}e^{-\frac{y}{6}}dy $. I only have the final answer:

> Using the *Transfer Formula*  we get the law of $Y=X^2$. $ \mathbb{P}_{Y}(dy) = \mathbb{I}_{]0;\infty[}(y)\frac{1}{\sqrt{6 \pi y}}e^{-\frac{y}{6}}dy$

Where does the $\frac{1}{2}$ go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\frac{1}{2}$ that you got is in fact there, but it is cancelled by an extra factor of $2$ corresponding to the fact that each value of $X^2$ has two equally likely preimages.

Personally I find this way of doing it is unnecessarily confusing; the way I would explain it is like this:

$$F_{X^2}(x)=P(X^2 \leq x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x<0 \\ P(|X| \leq \sqrt{x})=F_X(\sqrt{x})-F_X(-\sqrt{x}) & x \geq 0 \end{cases}$$

where I have used the fact that in your situation $F_X$ is continuous. (Otherwise a small modification is required.) You can then get the density by differentiation.

By the way the English buzzword that corresponds to what you're calling "transfer" is "pushforward". The actual theorem you stated is usually called "the law of the unconscious statistician" in English.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's a funny name for a theorem. Yes, I know that the easiest way is using CDFs and proceed with your reasoning, but it was required to reason by this funny formula to prove that we understand it.

Comment: @NC7 Using the method you were describing, the actual error is in the step where you change variables to $y=x^2$. The point is that if your change of variable mapping is not one-to-one, you cannot always just do this. In particular here, to do the integration correctly you can split $x \in \mathbb{R}$ into $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^-$ and then on each of those domains $x \mapsto x^2$ is one-to-one, and so you can definitely change variables to $y=x^2$.

Comment: Oh ty, now everything makes sense.

Comment: I had this idea to split the integral into those two intervals to get the right answer but was not sure if that was the "quickfix" to the problem or if it was just a coincidence that doing this leads to the correct answer.